# Is there any issue about use ftp functions in PHP running over windows task scheduler?

Tags: php

I have a code in PHP runing some FTP functions and it works fine when I execute it in a browser, it reads and record the file into my mysql database, updating a table that keeps the date and time of the last run. unfortunately when I try to do that with task scheduler, the only thing that executes is the date/time of the run, it completly ignore the ftp functions.
I already tried another task scheduler but got the same result.

```
$ftp_server = "server IP";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to 
$ftp_server");
$match[1] = "server IP"; 
$match[2] = "login";
$match[3] = "pw";
$match[4] = "";
$match[5] = "/xml/";
if (ftp_login($conn_id, $match[2], $match[3])) { 
    ftp_chdir($conn_id, $match[5]); 
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");
    foreach( $contents as $i=>$d) {
        $local_file=$d;
        $server_file=$d;
        ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII);
    }
}
$now=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$conexao=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');
$query="update parametros set leitura_xml='$agora' where id=1";
mysqli_query($conexao,$query) or die(error_log('gravacao da data de leitura xml '.mysqli_error($conexao)));
```

As I said, when running on a browser, it works very well, but when running on task scheduler, only the update to mysql works, which means that the code is runnig, but the ftp codes don´t. Sorry about my english.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you running this as a CMD Line PHP Script or are you calling the script via wget or some other HTTP method?

Comment: SQL injections and insecure FTP. This code has some alarming security concerns.

Comment: this is a local server in a intranet with no contact with internet, so I am not to much  concerned about security issues, thanks for the advise, the command line is C:\xampp\PHP\php.exe -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\max\ler_nfe_auto.php" I am using windows task scheduler

Comment: I tried to run it thru command line and I got the same result as from task scheduler, only the update works, FTP functions complete ignored.

Comment: is the (ftp_login($conn_id, $match[2], $match[3])) resolving to false? add an else{die('ftp login failed');} maybe that wlll shed some light?

Comment: But how it works fine when runned by browser? if it has a login failure it should happen in the browser too.but I will try it anyway.